# Find and Rename recursively in folders, subfolders and multiple files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I'm new with shellscript and I'm having some problems trying to do what I need...

I want to 'optimize' all my *.png images and found [this](http://es.kioskea.net/faq/7287-reducir-el-tamano-de-imagenes-png) so I made the bash  as it says with:

```
#!/bin/bash    
 pngnq -vf -s1 *.png    
 rename -nq8.png .png *-nq8*     
 optipng -o7 *.png
```

What this do is:

- `pngnq -vf -s1 *.png` takes a *png ofr example Image.png and craetes a copy named Image-nq8.png which is the one optimized
- `rename -nq8.png .png *-nq8*`makes Image-nq8.png become Image.png so you have the same as before but optimized (so you can have the same in the folders as you had before optimize) <= VERY IMPORTANT!
- `optipng -o7 *.png` does another optimization to Images.png without making any copy.

But now I have a problem:

If I write in console every line in order, it works ok on the folder I am but now I need to do it automatically and recursive. I explain my case:

note:  I say folder as a directory

I have a folder named ImagesFolder and inside I have other folders with more *.pngs and I want to run this bash in every subfolder of ImagesFolder but I don't know how to do it (as I said I'm new in unix and shellscripts and so on) and what I found on internet and tried didn't work or was a completly mess...

To understand it better what I have is something like:

```
ImagesFolder
  |-Folder1
  |     |- Folder12
  |     |      |-20 images here
  |     |- Folder13
  |     |      |- 10 images more here
  |     |-  _Folder <- I have some folder names that start with '_'
  |     |- 5 images here 
  |-more images and folders and subfoldrs
```

This is the structure and I want the script to run from ImagesFolder.

I tried with a for and a find in it, and with a find in console calling the script... tried too appling some examples I found here in stack but nothing... Probably is because as I don't really know how does this work I can't apply it just like that. Hope you can help me with this problem.

Thank you so much!

Edit: To run the script I have to go to ImageFolder, open a console and put `chmod u+x name_of_my_script` could this be a problem to run it into the subfolders? If yes, can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Why u+x not just +x?

Comment: well find on a web that I had to use u+x but now I'm using only +x. I'll have to see which is the difference

Comment: **As per comment from the OP, this is running on Fedora.**

Comment: Yes, it's a Fedora 12 with a GNU-bash, version 3.0.38(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bash script:

Create a new file `find_and_rename` and add the following lines:

- version with `replace`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  shopt -s globstar
  for f in **/*png; do 
      pngnq -vf -s1 "$f"

      # Uncomment the line below for a test run
      # rename -v -n 's/^(.*)\-nq8(.*)/$1$2/' "$f"

      # Comment the line below out for a test run
      rename -v 's/^(.*)\-nq8(.*)/$1$2/' "$f"

      optipng -o7 "$f"
  done
  ```
- version with `mv`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  shopt -s globstar
  for f in **/*png; do 
      pngnq -vf -s1 "$f"

      # Uncomment the line below for a test run
      # echo "$f  => ${f//-nq8/}"

      # Comment the line below out for a test run
      mv "$f" "${f//-nq8/}"

      optipng -o7 "$f"
  done
  ```

Make the file executable with:

```
chmod +x find_and_rename
```

Go into your folder `ImagesFolder`.

Start the script in this folder with.

```
<path_to_script>/find_and_rename
```

---

Example (without `pngnq` and `optipng`

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.png"
./Image-nq8.png
./sub/Image-nq8.png
./Image2-nq8.png

$ ./find_and_rename 
Image2-nq8.png renamed as Image2.png
Image-nq8.png renamed as Image.png
sub/Image-nq8.png renamed as sub/Image.png

$ find . -type f -name "*.png"
./Image2.png
./sub/Image.png
./Image.png
```

Comment: Hi, how do I call it? with ./Name_of_script when I'm on ImageFolder ? If I do this, it goes into ImageFolder, takes the first image and stops and leave me there the 2 images: Image.png and Image-nq8.png (I edited my question with the permission problems because maybe he stops for that) But the rename did nothing... and I suppose that this is not a permissions problem

Comment: Again updated =)

Comment: Thanks for the update and the help :) I am applying it with a little folder (which has subfolders and images too of course) so I can test quickly if it works

Your code enters on every subfolder and tooks the *.pngs and applies the first line (the one that makes the name-nq8.png copies) BUT then it finishes and nothing more happens... so I have the original image and the optimized one with the -nq8 on the name.... so seems that the rename does not work fine....

Comment: I tried your new code and tried both uncommenting the first rename and letting only the second one and I have the same: Image.png and  Image-nq8.png ... I'm on a fedora12 but I suppose that this is not the problem

Comment: I have tested the script without `pngnq ...` and `optipng ...`. It works in my environment.

Comment: And does it do the rename well? Do you only have iamge.png and not image-nq8.png ?!!

Comment: I have added a sample output of the test run

Comment: mmm I see.... but then why does it not work with optipng and pngnq? I supposse that I can do 1 script with pngnq and optipng taking *-nq8.png instead of *.png and then another one with the rename but I would like to do it all in one script only.... I'll try now if I have the same as u without pngnq and optipng.

Comment: If I run 
`#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*png; do 
    rename -v -n 's/^(.*)\-nq8(.*)/$1$2/' "$f"
done` It does nothing.... O.o the console prints nothing and stays in a normal way (I can write another command)

Comment: The complete script in one row?

Comment: Just now to try if it renames fine all the -nq8.png but not.... The thing is that this rename does not work on my case .. u put an example "Example (without pngnq and optipng" so I suppose u used it with only the rename line right? And tried the same to see if it worked for me too but it didn't

Comment: Add a line in the script: `echo "$i"` below the line `for f in **/*png; do` and check the output.

Comment: I did it (with $f not $i) and it prints the names of all the *.png in the directory and subdirectories like: image1.png - Folder1/Subfolder/Img.png and so on

Comment: What's your bash version `bash --version`

Comment: GNU-bash, version 3.0.38(1)

Comment: my version: GNU bash, Version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: replace the `replace … ` with `mv "$f" "${f//-nq8/}"`

Comment: Well... seems that this MV works really fine :) BUT in that script doesn't. I don't know why but if I run the script with pngnq- mv -optipng then it let me there the image.png and the image-nq8.png.... So what I'm I going to do is: make one script with pngnq and optipng. optipng will search only the -nq8.png. And another script with the mv. With that I can get what I need and I let you free A.B. :) 
Just a little question..... to make optipng take  the -nq8.png I have to change the line and I supposse that it has to become: `optipng -o7 *-nq8.png`maybe?